# regex rewrite url cluster

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've been trying to learn regex and its terribly complicated. I'm not even positive that it's possible to rewrite these URLs without doing them individually. I can do them individually (search & replace) but there are a few different clusters and there are 1000's of URLs (migration).

This is a Joomla site running acesef software. Here is an example URL from 1 particular cluster. The end of the URL is identical for old and new URL. Only the beginning directories have changed. So is there a way to match the end of the URL for all URLs in those particular directories from old to new and rewrite it with a single expression?

Old URL = www.domain.com/property-details/condominiums/3448-page-title

New URL = www.domain.com/bangkok/condos/rent/3448-page-title

I won't even bother posting what I've tried to write so far, because its so far off. I'm trying to get my feet wet with regex but this is a pretty complicated rewrite for a beginner.

Comment: I found [this resource](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to be really helpful for learning regular expressions. What you are looking to do should be entirely possible and probably even easy. Give it another try and show us what you got.

Comment: It would still be better to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well uh, at face value you could just use this:

`[^/]+$`

This will give you anything after the last `/` so in your example, you'd get `3448-page-title`